# Implementation of ACS in MetroApplications

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, acs

I tried of finding samples for implementing ACS in metroapplications using c#.

But I couldn't find any samples.

Can any one please help me with step by step details for implementing ACS in metro applications using XAML with C#.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of ACS for metro applications and the following may not be what you're looking for. Also, I'm not familiar with the gritty details of ACS. However, metro applications provide an API to enable single sign on to OAuth providers (Facebook, Live, Google, etc...).

There are code samples available @ http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122 and further details also available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465283.aspx

Comment: The sample do not do as expected, no tokens are returned when using windows 8 RTM.